# Use [d with ruby functions

Tags: include

I have been reading through the documentation on the `[d` command, and other related commands.
My understanding is that they allow you to search for the definition of the function that's currently under the cursor, and that they should search in included files, as well as the current file.
The search pattern they use is controlled by the `define` and `include` settings, and the defaults are set for C syntax.
I have managed to make searching work in the current buffer with this setting

```
setlocal define=^\\s*def\\s*\\(self.\\)\\?
```

Now if I place the cursor on the name of a method defined in the current file and enter `[<c-d>` I am taken to the method definition, but it still won't search included files.
Here is my current `include` setting.

```
setlocal include=^\\s*require\\(_relative\\)\\?
```

The search pattern successfully finds `require` and `require_relative` statements when I search manually, but `[d` still can't find function definitions in required files. I'm not sure if I need to change the `iskeyword` setting so vim can recognize the filenames. What can I do to make all this work? I would also be interested in ruby plugins that provide the same functionality.

Comment: [Universal Ctags](https://ctags.io/).

Comment: Ah, it looks like tags are probably what I'm actually looking for. Thanks.